# angular repeat with svg

Tags: angularjs, svg, repeat

I need to svg inside angular repeat, It looks work but it comes with error

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="{{getShape(data)}}"
```

and It's repeat more than it supposed to.
this is my simple prototype code. any idea?
http://plnkr.co/edit/EfINcm1Ee53MA9NptsFA?p=preview

Comment: Angular 1.1.1 is a very old version from 2012.  I doubt that you are using it in a current development project, but the way your javascript in your fiddle is written, it wouldn't work in a newer release.  I would start with ensuring that your code works with modern angular releases first.  also, all 1.1.x releases were considered unstable.

Comment: my real project use enough high version of angular, but error looks same.

Comment: ok, if your real project uses angular 1.2.x or higher, then you didn't reproduce your code properly, since the way you are declaring an angular controller has been depreciated, and you never declared an app module, so angular will never load.  the error in your svg is only echoing the fact that the expression can't ever be rendered.

Comment: bottom line, even if your project is using a newer release of angular, you presented an older release to us to illustrate your issue, and troubleshooting an older release on your behalf for a problem that exists in a newer, supported release isn't reasonable.

Comment: sorry, I was too rush to get answer. could you re-check url in content? I completely reproduce my code and error and out put are same.

Comment: this won't work, because the `<svg>` is being rendered before the call to `getShape()` is executed.  I don't believe there is a built in directive to solve this, the way `ng-href` would solve this problem for `href` attributes; in this case, I believe you would have to write your own directive to delay the rendering of the `<svg>` element.

Comment: this also might be a good read, since it seems to be related to what you are doing here http://alexandros.resin.io/angular-d3-svg/

Comment: your kindness helped me alot. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `d` attribute is being parsed before Angular has a chance to evaluate the expression and put in a "real" value.

To fix the problem, change:

```
<path d="{{getShape(data)}}"/>
```

to:

```
<path ng-attr-d="{{getShape(data)}}"/>
```

You may also need to do this for other SVG attributes if you use them. For example:

```
<circle ng-attr-cx="{{getCentreX()}}" ng-attr-cy="{{getCentreY()}}"/>
```

etc.

Comment: thanks! I already got same solution as yours thourgh comments tho